# Google Places Search AutoComplete filter results by Country in Swift 4

Tags: iphone, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to filter the results from the API (Google Places) country wise. 
I am aware I can do it, using code such as this:

```
  let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
  filter.type = .establishment
  filter.country = "SG"
```

SG is for Singapore but the thing is, where shall I place the code so that the results are filtered as per the country?

Comment: Please add your detailed code or explain it so people can help you.

Comment: Thanks! but I have solved the mystery , the above mentioned could was to be executed on the button click so i placed it in IBAction method for button click and it worked seamlessly.